# How to return proper error response for content-type text/csv?

Tags: java, json, spring, csv, spring-mvc

I have a servlet where in general I return `text/csv` as response. So a plain comma separated string.

BUT: in case of exceptions, I'd want to show just some error text as response.  But instead Spring generates a custom `ResponseEntity` object, then tries to convert this response to csv which obviously fails.

Is it possible to replace the requested format to `format=json`, and then just return the default Spring error response?

```
@RestController
public class CsvServlet {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", produces = "text/csv")
    @ResponseBody
    public String errorCsv(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return "some, plain, text";
    }
}
```

Usage: `localhost:8080/test?format=csv`

When having `spring.security.enabled=true`, this will first validate the basic auth credentials. If they fail, spring will automatically redirect to `/error` servlet.

Thereby `BasicErrorController.error()` method comes in, catching the error and generating a `ResponseEntity` with error attributes like `timestamp, exception, path, etc`.

Problem: now an `Object` of type `ResponseEntity` is returned. This is fine as long as the format parameter is either `?format=json/xml`. As the response can then be properly converted.

But in my special case, where I request `?format=csv`, the conversation will fail, leading to:

> Response could not be created:
>   org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not
>   find acceptable representation

This is partially true, moreover misleading because the user should directly see that the authentication credentials have been invalid. Because in general I'm accepting `csv`, but Spring and the mappers don't know how to convert a `ResponseEntity` to a plain format like csv.

**Question**: how can I preserve the original exception? So that I could just return a plain text error message. It would also be fine if I could return a `application/json` response in this case!

Comment: Did you try adding a ExecptionHandlerAdvice using `@ControllerAdvice`?

Comment: Yes, but that would catch only the `HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException`, but not the `BadCredentialsException` (which is catched by `BasicErrorController` as written above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround as follows for the moment: override the `/error` servlet handler, and if the `?format` parameter is not either `json/xml`, just return the original http status error without a body.

Thus spring cannot fail on converting the body into plain format and return the response correctly (but without exception details in the body).

```
@Controller
public class WorkaroundBasicErrorController extends BasicErrorController {
    //default constructor from ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration
    public DefaultBasicErrorController(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ServerProperties serverProperties,
                                       ObjectProvider<List<ErrorViewResolver>> errorViewResolversProvider) {
        super(errorAttributes, serverProperties.getError(), errorViewResolversProvider.getIfAvailable());
    }

    @RequestMapping
    @ResponseBody
    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> error(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String format = request.getParameter("format");

        return (StringUtils.containsAny(format, "json", "xml"))
            ? super.error(request)
            : new ResponseEntity<>(getStatus(request)); //neglect body for plain formats
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use a `void @ExceptionHandler`, and write error message directly in `HttpResponse`

Comment: As written above, any `@ExceptionHandler` is not catching in case of exceptions that trigger a redirect to `/error` servlet, like `BadCredentialsException`.